# CAShapeLayer is added to the view, but not around my button

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'd like to add a circular CAShapeLayer around my button that I've implemented with Storyboard. I'm doing this because I want to add a clockwise circle and pulsing animation similar to these two videos: [#1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3ltwjDJaMk&list=RDCMUCuP2vJ6kRutQBfRmdcI92mA&index=2) and [#2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYVazkkjOb8&list=RDCMUCuP2vJ6kRutQBfRmdcI92mA&index=1). I don't want a border as a shape is required. I've tried two approaches to and it is not going directly around my button.

I've tried it with viewDidLoad and viewDidLayoutSubviews. Both approaches put it in the top left corner. For brevity's sake, I only attached the viewDidLayoutSubviews below. The only change in viewDidLoad is the addition of self.view.layoutIfNeeded().

```
var wasCAShapeLayerAddedToButton = false
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        if !wasCAShapeLayerAddedToButton {
            wasCAShapeLayerAddedToButton = true
            
            startBiteButton.layer.cornerRadius = startBiteButton.frame.width / 2
            
            addCAShapeLayerToButton()
        }
    }
    
    func addCAShapeLayerToButton() {
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: startBiteButton.center, radius: startBiteButton.frame.width / 2, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        
        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 2
        trackLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        
        view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        
        recordLine.path = circularPath.cgPath
        recordLine.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0.42, green: 0.39, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
        recordLine.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        recordLine.lineWidth = 2
        recordLine.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        recordLine.strokeEnd = 0
        
        view.layer.addSublayer(recordLine)
        
        pulsatingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        pulsatingLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        pulsatingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        pulsatingLayer.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        pulsatingLayer.lineWidth = 2
        pulsatingLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        view.layer.addSublayer(pulsatingLayer)

        animatePulsatingLayer()
    }
```

[Here is how it's adding the shape.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv5vz.png)

Comment: Try setting `trackLayer/recordLine/pulsatingLayer.position = startBiteButton.center`.

Comment: The problem with *"For brevity's sake, I only attached the viewDidLayoutSubviews below."* is that we can't see what else you're doing. When I run your code on a button added to the root view, it lays out fine. From the image you've shown, it looks like you button is a subview of another view (and maybe another view, etc). Show enough code that can be run and will reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DonMag that's very fair, I appreciate the feedback. I solved the problem but thanks for the answer. It was my first question and now I'll be a better community member because of it.